# Reducir tamaño (mb) de las fotos realizadas con la cámara del movil

Tags: android, imagen, cámara

Muy buenas días/tardes

estoy realizando la llamada a la cámara usando este código

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(name));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

muestra la cámara , se toma la foto. 
y en el onActivityResult

```
new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {    
         private MediaScannerConnection msc = null; {
             msc = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this); msc.connect();
         }
         public void onMediaScannerConnected() { 
             msc.scanFile(name, null);
         }
         public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) { 
             msc.disconnect();
         } 
     };
```

el resultado de la foto es de gran peso (mb) y lo que busco es reducir dicho tamaño pero evitando la pedida de calidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bueno me respondo a mi mismo.. quizás no sea la mejor solución pero ahí les va. a mi me funciona.

en realidad no encontré la manera de que la cámara siempre tome las fotos con la mínima calidad y que sea aceptable (sin perder nitidez)

lo que se debe de hacer es . después de a ver grabado la imagen . se debe de realizar una copia de ella pero realizando un compress  y grabarla con el mismo nombre . para que lo sustituya .

```
public boolean savebitmap() {

    boolean result = false;
    // nombre = fecha + valoresGenerales.isTipoArchivoImagenExtencionPng;

    String filename = valoresGenerales.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_IMAGENOT +fecha + ".jpg";
    String extStorageDirectory = valoresGenerales.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_IMAGENOT;

    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File file = new File(filename );
    if (file.exists()) {
       //file.delete();
       //file = new File( filename + ".png");
       file = new File(extStorageDirectory, fecha + ".jpg");
       Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }

    int m_inSampleSize = 0;
    int m_compress = 100; 

    // 100 dejarlo original
    //  0  comprimir al maximo .. no se recomeinda.


    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = m_inSampleSize;  
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, bmOptions);
       // make a new bitmap from your file
       //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getName());

       outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, m_compress, outStream);
       outStream.flush();
       outStream.close();
       result = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {   
       e.printStackTrace();    
       result = false;
    }     
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return result;

 }
```

espero que les ayude.. si me sirvió.